# How to iterate through table cells and rows in React when I must iterate through multiple data arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I am trying to implement a table but since I have to iterate through multiple arrays for each row, my items wont get rendered in the correct row or are but the height gets messed up since I don't think I implement the table properly. Could someone please help?

```
<table id="customers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Cities</th>
            <th>Shops</th>
            <th>Map</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> {this.renderCountries()}</td>
            <td> {this.state.renderCities ? this.renderCities() :
                <p>{this.state.defaultCity}</p>} </td>
            <td> {this.state.renderShops ? this.renderShops() :
                <p>{this.state.defaultShopName}</p>} </td>
            <td> {this.state.renderMap ? this.renderMap() : null} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in my methods (renderCountries etc), I iterate through the particular array and return another component

```
   renderCountries = () => {
    return this.state.countries.map((country, index) => {
        return (
            <Column
                key={index}
                data={country}
            />
        )
    })
};

const Column = ({data}) => (<p> {data}</p>);
```

The way I have it so far is the only one that at least renders all items in the correct cell, however, it messes up the CSS (the second row, all items get moved about 200px down), I think its because I m not implementing the table properly, but when I change that to anything else, items wont get rendered correctly. If more info is needed please let me know.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want your resulting HTML to look like?

Comment: there would be 4 rows. 1 one all the countries, 2nd the citties (for chosen country), 3rd the shops for clicked city and 4rth the map for the chosen shop

Comment: You only have 1 row...

Comment: if i have 4 rows, the results are displayed not as a column but as a row. maybe thats a css question but not sure how to change that

Comment: Your table has 2 rows, based on your HTML code.  Post an example at https://jsfiddle.net/